# What is the difference in using "on va faire la fête" with CONJUGAISON of "faire"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, futur-proche

What is the difference in using "on va faire la fête" et "on va fais la fete" ou "on va fait la fete?

Comment: Can you tell us your native language please? faire la fête does not change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in speaking about differences as only the first form is correct (the other two mean nothing).

- on va faire la fête
- <s>on va fais la fete</s>
- <s>on va fait la fete</s>

The second verb in these combinations of two  verbs is never conjugated and must always appear in its infinitive form. This combination of "aller" with other verbs in the infinitive is used to express a near future.

[futur proche](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-12541.php)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are conjugating a verb with an auxiliary, the famous "deux verbes se suivent le second se met toujours à l'infinitif" is the rule, meaning when you have 2 verbes back to back, the second one will be in its infinitive form. If you want to conjugate *faire*, you must remove the verb *aller* and then you can say on fait la fête (now), on fera la fête (sometime in the future), on a fait la fête (we did it and it's over).